# CheckBox to Populate a Date/Time Field

Tags: apex, visualforce

Hi I created a Visual force page for opportunities and displayed check box what I am looking after if checkbox == true then a date/Time field in opportunity need to populate with today's date.

Can anybody help me out with some sample piece of code please

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8578748/display-a-text-field-after-a-checkbox-is-checked-in-visualforce                 The above link can help you get started !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apex method:

```
public Opportunity oop { get; set; }
public Boolean myCheckbox { get; set; }

// Constructor
public YourClass()
{
    // Defaulf value of the checkbox
    myCheckbox = false;
}

public PageReference setDatetime()
{
    if(myCheckbox)
        oop.MyDatetime__c = Datetime.now();
    else
        oop.MyDatetime__c = null;

    return null;
}
```

Visualforce:

```
Checkbox: 
<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!myCheckbox}">
    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="none" action="{!setDatetime}"/>
</apex:inputCheckbox>
```

Comment: Hi mastOr this thanks for the reply, im not displaying any input fields in visual force page only displaying the records. if check box is checked and saved then date/time field should populate in UI page and record need to be save

Comment: HI, just updated my code. If checkbox is clicked - the date field populated with current date/time. I think this is what you mean an need?

Comment: hi mastOr im sorry abt i didnt clearly mentioned the question im really sry abt that, i displayed the opp records on vf page with <apex:inputCheck box/> but not the custom field when the checkbox is true then the date/time field in opp should populate with today date(Datetime.now()).

Comment: Just updated my example for use with a normal checkbox. Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is quite common, I have few articles about this topic. I think the closest to what you are looking for is: http://www.eltoro.it/ArticleViewer?id=a07A000000NPRjKIAX